# clang says call to void consteval function is not a constant expression

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, constant-expression, consteval

clang(trunk) gives an error for the following code:

```
consteval void f() {}

int main() 
{ 
    f();  // error: call to consteval function 'f' is not a constant expression
          // note: subobject of type 'void' is not initialized
}
```

while gcc(trunk) compiles this without error.

I feel this is probably a clang bug, since both gcc and clang accept this code:

```
consteval int g() { return 42; }

int main() 
{ 
    g();  // ok
}
```

Here's the [code](https://godbolt.org/z/8TsYGW) to play with.

So is this a clang bug, or is the code ill-formed, or have ub, or something else?

---

Edit: I feel it might be relevant to point out that clang allows calling `f` from other functions if they are also consteval. It only gives the error when `f` is called from non-consteval  functions:

```
consteval int h() 
{ 
    f();       // ok
    return 42; 
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o4Wxaf).

Comment: Does it work if f is constexpr? (when forcing constexpr, like `constexpr int x = (f(), 5);`)

Comment: clang does [not yet claim to implement `consteval`](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx20).

Comment: @Dani No, it gives the same [error](https://godbolt.org/z/Tv5Y5f).

Comment: @Barry True, but I was under the impression that it's been implemented in trunk for a while. So it's just an incomplete feature then? Still an odd error though.

Comment: Then I would say it’s a compiler bug. The rationale is `std::sort` for instance.

Comment: Does this mean clang doesn’t support constexpr sort right now? It’s a c++20 feature, so they don’t have to yet.

Comment: @Dani Yes, I don't think `constexpr` `sort` is supported yet. But how is that relevant here?

Comment: @Dani What does `sort` have to do with `consteval`? It's not a `consteval` function.

Comment: BTW: Whats is the sense of consteval with a void function?

Comment: @Klaus Ha, good question, didn't think of that :p I guess it could be useful to have a named function that does a bunch of `static_assert`s.

Comment: @Klaus: The function can still modify its arguments if they are declared in a constexpr/eval function. For example, std::sort.

Comment: @Barry: it’s about the situation in the comments, where f is constexpr

Comment: @Dani: Perfect! Thats it! Thanks!

Comment: @Klaus Yes, arguments can be modified. I was thinking of a void function with no arguments, as in the question. Use cases for that are less obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a Clang bug that was both introduced between version 10 and version 11, and [fixed](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/038edf6029bafe70b1f7165abe2b0e61ddf506b3) last month. The implementation of `consteval` in Clang is mostly, but not entirely, complete, and this bug arose after one of the patches adding more complete `consteval` support.

Details: the top-level entry point into Clang's constant evaluator checks whether the result is a permitted result of a constant expression -- it checks that the result doesn't contain pointers to automatic storage duration or a temporary or similar. But this check was never updated to accommodate for `void` being a literal type, and would reject values of type `void` for being "uninitialized". This was never noticed before the addition of `consteval` support, because all top-level constant evaluations were of non-`void` types.

Comment: Indeed, it now compiles on [trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/TEq3fx). Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it compiles now, but a linker error occurs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69513993/immediate-functions-returning-void-in-clang

Comment: It's got nothing to do with void. It's the context of the call. I get an error with unsigned long long. But only in a particular context, the same function works fine in other contexts.

Comment: ```static consteval Nat size() { return H::size() * Product<T...>::size(); }  Product succ() const { Nat x = size(); return Product((rep + 1) % x); }ring.cxx:399:34: error: call to consteval function 'Product<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1...>::size' is not a constant expression
  Product succ() const { Nat x = size(); return Product((rep + 1) % x); }```

Answer (score 0):

What I found [c++20 final draft](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf) is:

> 9.2.5  The constexpr and constevals pecifiers[dcl.constexpr]
> (2) A constexpr or consteval specifier used in the declaration of a function declares that function to be a constexpr function. A function or constructor declared with the consteval specifier is called animmediate function. A destructor, an allocation function, or a deallocation function shall not be declared with the consteval specifier.

> (3) The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following requirements:

> 3.1 its return type (if any) shall be a literal type;

and

> 6.8  Types [basic.types]

> (10) A type is a literal type if it is :

> (10.1) cv void

> ...

As this `void` is a valid return type for a `consteval` function.

Comment: _The "if any" seems to make void valid here._ "if any" covers constructors' and destructors' absence of return types. `void f();` **does have** a return type. «_cv_ `void`» is a [literal type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.types#def:literal_type), "if any" is not for it.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Thanks for the explanation. That makes void a valid return type for a conexpr/consteval function.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer how do you construct an object of `void`? It literally received that name from K&R for being nothing. I guess that's wher clang's architecture fails

Comment: Actually, I don't doubt that the definition of `f` is fine. The question is about the call `f()` which is where the error comes from. Note that clang allows calling `f` from other `consteval` functions. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4P1TTb).

Comment: _"if any" covers constructors' and destructors' absence of return types_ Actually, only constructors' absence, destructors are not allowed to be `consteval`.

Comment: I edited the question a bit with possibly relevant information, if you could take a look.

Comment: @cigien: I can call consteval or constexpr funcs from non consteval/constexpr functions always.I did not read about any restriction in that direction. Typically a compiler optimizes that call out.

Comment: No, there are language restrictions on calling functions from certain contexts that have nothing to do with compiler optimizations.