# Immediate functions returning void in Clang

Tags: c++, clang++

Clang++ produces linker error if one calls immediate function returning `void` not from a context of another immediate function as in the example:

```
consteval void f(int * x) { 
    if(x) *x = 1; 
}

consteval int g() {
    int y = 0;
    f(&y);
    return y;
}

int main() {
    (void)g(); //ok everywhere
    f(nullptr); //linker error in Clang
}
```

The error is:

```
undefined reference to `f(int*)'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PT8ezfnrW

The error disappears if the immediate function returns anything but `void`, for example:

```
consteval int f(int * x) { 
    if(x) *x = 1; 
    return 1;
}
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hfzrM688E

Is it just a bug in Clang?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364918/clang-says-call-to-void-consteval-function-is-not-a-constant-expression

Comment: @KamilCuk, thanks for the reference. It is said there that the bug is fixed, but it does not look so. At least it is manifested differently now.

Comment: LLVM bugzilla and stackoverflow are 2 distinctly different websites. And this here is an obvious bug. :-)

Comment: Add these to the top of the file:  `#ifndef __cpp_consteval` and `#error consteval not supported` and `#endif`

Comment: Hmm, this must be a bug. There shouldn't be anything to link if it's `consteval`.

Comment: I reported this bug to llvm: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52183